# Is Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression(expr) exposed now?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to use the method:

Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression(expr)

but I don't want to use Microsoft.Web.Mvc, is this call supported in asp.net mvc now?

Answer (score 4):

No.

Still in Futures and therefore Microsoft.Web.Mvc only.

Answer (score 0):

installing Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures resolved the issue for me , i had mvc 5 version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).